# ByteString to Json format

Tags: haskell

I´m building a connector that call an API and return some data in `json` format. The data type when I receive the rest response is `ByteString`, so 
once I render with Scotty http server I use `aeson`. Looking the aeson documentation I see the use of:

```
instance ToJSON ByteString
instance FromJSON ByteString
```

But it's not compiling since `not instance for (Generic ByteString)`

```
responseMovie :: ActionM ()
responseMovie = do movie <- extractUriParam "movie"
                   response <- liftAndCatchIO $ simpleGetRequest $ searchMovieQuery movie
                   json (show response)
```

But the format I render is Strings.

Any idea what I´m doing wrong?

```
"\"{\\\"Title\\\":\\\"Mad Max\\\",\\\"Year\\\":\\\"1979\\\",\\\"Rated\\\":\\\"R\\\",\\\"Released\\\":\\\"21 Mar 1980\\\",\\\"Runtime\\\":\\\"88 min\\\",\\\"Genre\\\":\\\"Action, Adventure, Sci-Fi, Thriller\\\",\\\"Director\\\":\\\"George Miller\\\",\\\"Writer\\\":\\\"James McCausland (screenplay), George Miller (screenplay), George Miller (original story), Byron Kennedy (original story)\\\",\\\"Actors\\\":\\\"Mel Gibson, Joanne Samuel, Hugh Keays-Byrne, Steve Bisley\\\",\\\"Plot\\\":\\\"In a self-destructing world, a vengeful Australian policeman sets out to stop a violent motorcycle gang.\\\",\\\"Language\\\":\\\"English\\\",\\\"Country\\\":\\\"Australia\\\",\\\"Awards\\\":\\\"4 wins & 7 nominations.\\\",\\\"Poster\\\":\\\"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTM4Mjg5ODEzMV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMDc3NDk0NA@@._V1_SX300.jpg\\\",\\\"Ratings\\\":[{\\\"Source\\\":\\\"Internet Movie Database\\\",\\\"Value\\\":\\\"7.0/10\\\"},{\\\"Source\\\":\\\"Rotten Tomatoes\\\",\\\"Value\\\":\\\"90%\\\"},{\\\"Source\\\":\\\"Metacritic\\\",\\\"Value\\\":\\\"73/100\\\"}],\\\"Metascore\\\":\\\"73\\\",\\\"imdbRating\\\":\\\"7.0\\\",\\\"imdbVotes\\\":\\\"172,382\\\",\\\"imdbID\\\":\\\"tt0079501\\\",\\\"Type\\\":\\\"movie\\\",\\\"DVD\\\":\\\"19 Nov 1997\\\",\\\"BoxOffice\\\":\\\"N/A\\\",\\\"Production\\\":\\\"s\\\",\\\"Website\\\":\\\"N/A\\\",\\\"Response\\\":\\\"True\\\"}\""
```

In case it was unclear here I paste my program

```
searchMovieQuery :: String -> String
searchMovieQuery movie = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey="++ omdbKey ++ "&t=" ++ movie

startServer :: IO ()
startServer = do
              print ("Starting Omdb server at port: " ++ show port)
              scotty port routes

routes ::  ScottyM()
routes = do get "/movie/:movie" responseMovie

responseMovie :: ActionM ()
responseMovie = do movie <- extractUriParam "movie"
                   liftAndCatchIO $ print ("Finding movie" ++ movie)
                   bsResponse <- liftAndCatchIO $ simpleGetRequest $ searchMovieQuery movie
                   liftAndCatchIO $ print ("Response:" ++ (show bsResponse))
                   txtResponse <- liftAndCatchIO $ transform bsResponse
                   json txtResponse

extractUriParam :: LazyText.Text -> ActionM String
extractUriParam param = Web.Scotty.param param


transform :: Inter.ByteString -> IO LazyText.Text
transform bs = do txtResponse <- case (decode bs) of
                                      Just value -> return value
                                      Nothing -> return (LazyText.pack $ "Nothing to share:" ++ (show bs))
                  return txtResponse


simpleGetRequest :: String -> IO ByteString
simpleGetRequest uri = do
                    manager <- newManager defaultManagerSettings
                    request <- parseRequest uri
                    response <- makeRequest manager request
                    return $ responseBody response

makeRequest :: Manager -> Request -> IO (Response ByteString)
makeRequest manager request =  httpLbs request manager
```

I use decode as you mention once that I transform ByteString to Text.
But now in the decode B`yteString -> Text`, in the `Maybe` is going always in the `Nothing`, even having data.

Comment: Aeson can be [decode](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.4.1.0/docs/Data-Aeson.html#v:decode) from ByteString, the first thing to do may be replace `"\\\""` to `"\""`.

Comment: Mmmm weird Json $ decode response does not compile

Comment: The JSON string seems ill-format, the correct format should be: `"{\"Title\":...}"`, not `"\"{\\\"Title\\\":...}\""`

Comment: @assembly.jc: that is probably due to the `show` part, which thus wraps it in a "representation layer".

Comment: Yeah that’s why as I mentioned I was trying Json $ decode response, but it seems decore with byteString is not compiling

Comment: This question is very unclear. What do you mean by "connector"? Why have you pasted some string at the end of the question?

Comment: I mean is a Rest connector, and I paste the data to show the format that is being sent

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53295993/1651941

Comment: I try in GHCi: `jsonStr = "{\"Title\":\"Mad Max\",\"Year\":\"1979\",\"R...`,  `decode (pack jsonStr)::Maybe Value`, can successfully decode. What is the error meesage in your case?

Comment: You start with a `ByteString`, then use `show` to get a `String` representation of the byte string, then use `json` to *encode* that string in JSON. Depending on what you really want to do, you can probably just use `response` as is.

Comment: @assembly.jc I update my question, I cannot make it works with decode

Comment: You may need just decode `ByteString` to `Text`. see: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.3.1/docs/Data-Text-Encoding.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly:

- you know that the `ByteString` returned from `simpleGetRequest` contains JSON
- you don't care about the specific contents of that JSON
- you want to pass the `ByteString` to [`json` from Scotty](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/scotty-0.11.2/docs/Web-Scotty.html#v:json)

`aeson` provides a type [`Value`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.4.2.0/docs/Data-Aeson-Types.html#t:Value) to represent JSON in general, without any details of what fields are present.  So one option is:

```
let response = case decode bsResponse of
    Nothing -> Null
    Just value -> value
json response
```

where `Null` is one of the constructors of [`Value`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.4.2.0/docs/Data-Aeson-Types.html#t:Value).  Of course you can make other choices of what to do in the `Nothing` case.

Another option, which saves the round-trip of parsing JSON & then re-encoding it, is to use [`raw :: ByteString -> ActionM ()` from Scotty](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/scotty-0.11.2/docs/Web-Scotty.html#v:raw)

The `Generic` way of defining `ToJSON` and `FromJSON`, which you mention at the top of your post, works for user-defined types, when each field of the type already has `ToJSON` / `FromJSON` defined.  `ByteString` isn't like that.  In general, `ByteString` can contain any bytes.  It is often used in different parts of the same program to represent different types of value, which should be represented differently in JSON.  So we have to be explicit about what we're expecting & how we want to encode it.

Comment: raw function is just what I need, thank you so much for!